# Rewrite with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How can I make links like

```
http://mywebsite.com/page.php?page_id=Idofthepage&id=idofthearticle
http://mywebsite.com/page.php?currentpage=currentid
http://mywebsite.com/page.php?page_id=hereId
```

To be

```
http://mywebsite.com/page/Idofthepage/idofthearticle
http://mywebsite.com/page/currentpage/currentid
http://mywebsite.com/page/idofthepage
```

I don't know how to do it because of ID's and they change.. I mean while I'm on `page_id=1?id=5` and next is `page_id=1?id=35`?
For static pages like `/index.php`, `contact.php` etc I know how to do it. But here I don't.

So far I have this to clear .php from url's.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```